# Como criar diretiva de uma função js

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma função pra validar data:

```
   function validateDate(id) {
     var RegExPattern = /^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\.\-\/](0?[13578]|1[02])    [\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\.\-\/](0?[13456789]|1[012])[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\.\-\/]0?2[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(29[\.\-\/]0?2[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00)))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$/;

     if (!((id.value.match(RegExPattern)) && (id.value!=''))) {
      return false;

       }
      else
     return true;
   }
```

Como ficaria pra me criar uma diretiva dessa função pra usar direto no input?

Comment: Depende, poderia fornecer mais detalhes? @War Lock

Comment: Não há necessidade de criar uma diretiva para validar data, use o filter date: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: E para verificar se é uma data: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo nome da sua função, ela se trata de uma função de validação.

Você deve configurar os *validators* no `ngModelController` da *directive*. O `ngModelController` é o 4º parâmetro da propriedade `link` de uma *directive*.

Por exemplo:

```
angular.module("Modulo").directive("diretriz", function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function ($s, $e, $a, $c) {
            $c.$validators.data = function (mv, vv) {
                // mv é o valor na sua variável.
                // vv é o valor na view.
                if ( vv === "" ) {
                    return true;
                }
                vv = vv.split("/");
                if ( vv.length !== 3 ) {
                    return false;
                }
                vv.reverse();
                vv = vv.join("-");
                return !isNaN(Date.parse(vv)));
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Note que na propriedade `link`, a função associada a ela aceita 4 parâmetros:

- `$s` é o escopo;
- `$e` é o elemento encasulado em jQuery ou jQuerylite;
- `$a` são os atributos do elemento;
- `$c` é o `ngModelController`.

O atributo `$validators` do `ngModelController` possui os "validadores" da sua diretriz. Eles retornam `true` ou `false`. Todos os *validators* são executados durante o processo de validação, sendo que o(s) elemento(s) associado com a diretriz são considerados válidos se e somente se todos os *validators* retornarem `true`.

Uma característica interessante dos *validators* no Angular, é que quando um elemento possui o atributo `required`, é checado apenas se seu valor é diferente de `false` (inclusive valores que podem ser coercidos para `false`, como o número `0`).

Como consequência, o seu *validator* pode retornar `true` quando o campo estiver vazio (mesmo que este seja um valor inválido), e você pode forçar que o campo seja preenchido utilizando o atributo `required`. Desta forma, você pode diferenciar quando o elemento é inválido por conter um valor que não atende às suas regras, ou quando o elemento é vazio, e inclusive decorar o elemento através de CSS quando um caso ou de outro sem nenhum código adicional (observe as classes adicionadas pelo Angular ao elemento quando este é inválido, vazio ou válido).

O `ngModelController` possui vários outros campos interessantes além do `$validator`, como o `$parsers` e o `$formatters`. Vale muito a pena dar uma olhada neles na documentação.

**Edição**

Não utilizei sua RegEx porque ela esta demasiada complexa, ainda mais quando o browser possui recursos nativos para interpretar datas. Assim, o validador que escrevi converte a data no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` para o formato `yyyy-mm-dd` (ISO 8601), aceito nativamente pelo browser no método `Date.parse`.

Apesar de não utilizar RegEx, tentei preservar a mesma semântica do seu método. Assim os dois devem ser equivalentes (com a vantagem que o meu checa se o ano é bissexto).

Comment: Como ficaria de fato, a chamada no meu html?

Comment: Você pode definir um template de um input e incluir o elemento no seu HTML, ou você pode trocar a linha `restrict: "E"` por `restrict: "A"` e adicionar como atributo ao elemento que deseja realizar a validação.

Comment: Gobbo A. De Oliv tem como tu editar sua resposta, com minha função completa? vou editar a pergunta com a função completa, coloca ai como ficaria com ela.pois não estou conseguindo, é uma função q verifica se a data é valida, retorna true ou false;

Comment: Fiz a edição, porém não utilizei exatamente o seu método. Sua RegEx esta estranha, e complexa demais, ainda mais quando o browser possui recursos nativos (`Date.parse`) para interpretar e validar datas. Veja minha edição no final da pergunta.

Comment: Dessa forma valida tbm anos bisexto?

Comment: Sim. É o formato nativo e aconselhado de se manipular datas.

Comment: Obrigado...funcionou aqui

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira  aproveitando o tópico, tem como você postar a validação junto ao html rodando? se possível? pois estou começando a estudar angular,inclusive eu que respondi a ele a função com a expressão regular em outro tópico, e estou precisando disso também mas no angular, e de cara não consegui implementar a diretiva.Se puder postar como ficaria na prática no jsfidle, ou código puro iria me ajudar, valeu.